# Using google sheets query to determine the amount of days an Id is offline during each month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a google sheet that keeps track of when an Id will go offline and when it will be back. Each row in this sheet has the Id of the object, the date it goes offline, the date it comes back, and a boolean for whether to count it or not.

On Sheet2 I want to keep track of how many days the object was offline each month for the past year.

Example Data

```
Id      StartDate   EndDate    Bool
999999  1/5/2020    1/10/2020  TRUE
999999  12/25/2020  1/4/2020   TRUE
888888  10/1/2019   1/20/2020  TRUE
888888  1/21/2020   1/30/2020  TRUE
```

Sheet2

```
Id      2/1/2020  1/1/2020  12/1/2019  11/1/2019  10/1/2019  9/1/2019
999999     15        15        15         15         15         15
888888     111       111       111        111        111        111
```

Desired Output

```
Id      2/1/2020  1/1/2020  12/1/2019  11/1/2019  10/1/2019  9/1/2019
999999     0         9          7          0          0         0
888888     0         29         31         30         31        0
```

[Google Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QyfpwgrF7XT7eP1q4pDjIkuZkN-Za9VDvV3e9EvT9gA/edit?usp=sharing)

To find the amount of days a product has been offline I've made this

```
=SUM(QUERY(Sheet1!$A:$D,CONCATENATE("select datediff(C,B) where D=TRUE and A=",$A2)))
```

However it does not check whether the days are within the month, I was considering having if statements in the datediff function, something which would work like this,

```
select datediff(ifs(StartDate<1stOfTheMonth,1stOfTheMonth,StartDate>1stOfTheMonth and StartDate<EndOfMonth,StartDate,StartDate>EndOfMonth,EndOfMonth),ifs(EndDate>EndOfMonth,EndOfMonth,EndDate<EndOfMonth and EndDate>StartOfMonth,EndDate,EndDate<1stOfTheMonth,1stOfTheMonth)) where ...
```

If the start date is before the month begins, it counts days from the start of the month, if the start date is during the month, it counts days from the start date, if the start date is after the month, it returns 0 days because it counts from the end of the month to the end of the month.

If the end date is after the end of the month, it counts to the end of the month, if the end date is during the month, it counts to the end date, if the end date is before the month it returns 0 days because it counts from the start of the month to the start of the month.

I would expect it to work but I don't know how I could implement it into the query function.

Comment: @Inticks I've got a solution for you, but it would be a little easier to demonstrate if you would change your link sharing from View only to Editable.  I'll share it in an answer as well, but it might be easier to understand if I installed it on a shared sheet for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a fresh tab on your sample sheet, Place this formula in A1, then format the top row as Format>Number>More Formats>Custom Number format:

mmm yyyy

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!B2:B)*(MAX(Sheet1!C2:C-Sheet1!B2:B)+1),1,0)/(MAX(Sheet1!C2:C-Sheet1!B2:B)+1)+2,{ROW(Sheet1!B2:B),Sheet1!A2:A,IF((Sheet1!B2:B+SEQUENCE(1,MAX(Sheet1!C2:C-Sheet1!B2:B)+1,0)<=Sheet1!C2:C)*Sheet1!D2:D,IFERROR(EOMONTH(Sheet1!B2:B+SEQUENCE(1,MAX(Sheet1!C2:C-Sheet1!B2:B)+1,0),-1)+1),)},MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!B2:B)*(MAX(Sheet1!C2:C-Sheet1!B2:B)+1),1,0),MAX(Sheet1!C2:C-Sheet1!B2:B)+1)*{0,1}+{2,3}),"select Col2,Count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1 order by Col2 desc label Col2'ID'")))
```